# Objective C iOS drawing rectangles on an arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

I need to draw a custom arc in an iOS application. The picture demonstrate how I want to draw the arc, using small rectangles. I have tried to use CGContextAddArc which draws a line, but I cant understand how to use objects(rectangle) and not just a straight line. Is this even possible or should I choose another approach?

Here is the arc i want to draw:

[image]

Comment: Check this http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/

Comment: First, why rectangles? Why not just lines with a thickness? They are essentially the same thing unless you want to add a different fill and stroke colour? Second, is this a dynamic control?

Comment: Will check the link. Line or rectangle doesnt matter, in android I can just pass a rectangle object to a method(addArc), thats why I was thinking in rectangles. And no, this is not dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I draw this kind of thing using UIBenizerCurve from QuartzCore framework. I do something demo code as following,

in class .h file

```
struct angleRanges{
    float startRange;
    float endRange;
}angle_Range;
```

Provide your ranges of angle.
And in .m file

```
#import <tgmath.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define RADIUS 125.0f
#define METER_END_LIMIT 100.f
#define CIRCLE_STROKE_PATH_WIDTH 30.f
#define ANGAL -90.f

NSInteger numberOfParts = METER_END_LIMIT/5;
    float angleRange = 0;

for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex <= numberOfParts; loopIndex++){
    angle_Range.startRange = 0;
    angle_Range.endRange   = 360 - (180.f * angleRange)/METER_END_LIMIT;
    double actualLineAngle = angle_Range.endRange - angle_Range.startRange;

    float startAngle = actualLineAngle - 0.5;
    float endAngle = actualLineAngle + 0.5;

    startAngle =  DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle);
    endAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(endAngle);
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y + RADIUS/2)
                                                         radius:(RADIUS+CIRCLE_STROKE_PATH_WIDTH/3)
                                                     startAngle:startAngle
                                                       endAngle:endAngle
                                                      clockwise:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shapeLayer setFrame: self.frame];
    [shapeLayer setPath: [aPath CGPath]];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5;
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [aPath closePath];

    angleRange = angleRange + 5.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try to draw each element individually, try drawing a single arc with a large width and a dash pattern. For example, a line width of 10.0 and a dash pattern of 1,10 will draw an effect very similar to the one you are trying to achieve - a series of 1x10 rectangles, placed 10 points apart, on the path you specify.

The relevant CGContext functions are `CGContextSetLineWidth` and `CGContextSetLineDash`.

Comment: Smart suggestion. However I need to draw the lines at specific angles, like a meter. I'll upvote you since I didn't mention that in the post. Reformers answer works, but is more complex.

Comment: @Zeezer, yes this soliution i also tried but real problem and challenge this solution i unable can't rotate those dash lines toward the center of circle. Also even it will possible to rotate those border lines towards center then code become more complex than my written code.

Comment: @Reformer I'm not sure what you mean, but I hade it working as shown in my picture, and the dashed lines were rotade against the center. But in order to act as a meter I think that you need to use angles, and not patterns.